# nginx save every request every made including headers

Tags: nginx, php, logging

I want to set up a nginx rule that will log every request ever made on my site including cookies. For example for a single php script I can get the
full request body with this code:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

But I want to log every request that is being made on php scripts on my nginx server. Any idea how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you wanna do it ?

Comment: For my own reasons. There is a hacker that gets acces I want to know how. :)

Comment: You could use tcpdump with port specification to sniff all the traffic going towards that particular tcp port. You could also specify source IP if you know the IP, you can always block it using fail2ban. 
e.g.: ```tcpdump tcp port 80```

Comment: tcpdump tcp port 80


does this log everything? his ip, his headers, request uri etc ?

How do save it on a folder on each request?\